# Why is my button taking two clicks to toggle a function? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, onclick

I have created a webpage with a button. When you click it, it turns from the default black to pink and when you click it again, it turns purple. For some reason, it is taking two clicks to turn from the default black button to pink. Please help me figure out how to make it so it changes on the first click (or if you know a better way to carry this out)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Events Lab</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    
        <h1 id="changeh1"> Clicking the button will change its color <h1>
        
        <button onclick="changeStyle()" type="button" name="button" id="buttonStyle">My color will change!</button>
    
<script src="script.js"></script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function changeStyle() {


        //sets variable "button" to connect to HTML ID "buttonStyle"
        var button = document.getElementById("buttonStyle"),
            click = false;
            
        button.onclick = function() {
            click = !click;                                     
         
        //toggles background color back and forth between pink and purple when you click button
        button.style.background = click? "#ff0066": "#9933ff";  
         
        //toggles text back and forth between "I am now pink!" and "I am now purple!"
        document.getElementById('buttonStyle').innerHTML = click? 'I am now pink!': 'I am now purple!';
}
}


let buttonClick = document.getElementById('buttonStyle');
buttonClick.addEventListener('click', changeStyle);
```

CSS

```
body{
text-align: center;
font-family: Helvetica;
}


button {
width:350px;
height: 125px;
background-color: black;
color:white;
border: 5px solid black;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added eventListener two times, one in HTML onclick, the other one in Javascript with addEventListener.

You can make Javascript code as simple as follows:

```js
var click = false;
let buttonClick = document.getElementById('buttonStyle');

function changeStyle() {
        click = !click;

        //toggles background color back and forth between pink and purple when you click button
        buttonClick.style.background = click? "#ff0066": "#9933ff";  
         
        //toggles text back and forth between "I am now pink!" and "I am now purple!"
        buttonClick.innerHTML = click? 'I am now pink!': 'I am now purple!';
}
```

```css
body{
text-align: center;
font-family: Helvetica;
}


button {
width:350px;
height: 125px;
background-color: black;
color:white;
border: 5px solid black;
font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Events Lab</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    
        <h1 id="changeh1"> Clicking the button will change its color <h1>
        
        <button onclick="changeStyle()" type="button" name="button" id="buttonStyle">My color will change!</button>
    
<script src="script.js"></script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript, you wrote the below codelines.

```
let buttonClick = document.getElementById('buttonStyle');
buttonClick.addEventListener('click', changeStyle);
```

Also in your html you wrote the code like the below.

```
<button onclick="changeStyle()" type="button" name="button" id="buttonStyle">My color will change!</button>
```

Meaning, when you click the `My color will change!` button, the changeStyle function will be called twice.
Why?
One from the event defined in html code and the other one from the event defined in javascript code.
In case you remove the above 2 codelines in javascript it will work correctly.
Or else, you can remove the onclick event in the html code like this :

```
<button type="button" name="button" id="buttonStyle">My color will change!</button>
```